# Why easiest path from Big Bang to Heat Death is not followed by nature?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, universe, big-bang

Why after Big Bang it is not going to Heat Death in the easiest path, actually the energy can get distributed uniformly to all directions. Instead we see the energy in Big Bang is being converted to atoms, then the stars, galaxy etc. are formed. Isn't these formations making the path to Heat Death more distant? Any natural law explain these formation of concentrated energy structures like atoms, stars, galaxy etc.

Comment: " atoms, ." are the observables in our universe that the standard model of particle physics (  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model)  is successful in modelling,  "stars, galaxy" are observables that .the  big bang and further models try to model tmathematically  using the standard model of particle physics.

Comment: You assume, without an apparent good reason for that, that there is an "easier path" than the current system trajectory we're on. Sounds speculative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're asking why the universe started out in a highly ordered state, and not in a highly disordered state (which would be immediate heat death).

The answer is we don't know, because we don't have physics laws that hold at the Big Bang. Furthermore I suspect that even if we did, we won't be able to predict the *initial conditions* - here meaning the state the universe started in. An everyday comparison is, if you have a ball and throw it upwards at speed $v$, Newton's laws can predict how the ball will move and how long it will take to fall back down to the Earth, but it can't predict $v$.